# cannot create a small Javascript application

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

When I create an HTML document on my computer with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function newDoc() {
    window.location.assign("http://www.yahoo.com")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Go to Yahoo!" onclick="newDoc()">

</body>
</html>
```

and try to run it by clicking on it, everything goes just fine - the JS code in the file gets properly executed: the document opens up in my default browser, and when I click on "Go to Yahoo!" button, the Yahoo page gets opened.

But when I create a small "load.js" file with the following content:

```
function newDoc() {
    window.location.assign("http://www.w3schools.com")
}
newDoc()
```

and try running it by clicking on it nothing happens. And I get this message:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` You're trying to go to _w3schools_

Comment: On my computer it works fine.

Comment: @PaulS. - "You're trying to go to w3schools" - :) - In fact, I just came here from there.

Comment: @brilliant yea that's one of  the reason people ends up with many propblems and seeks help in other resourses.

Comment: btw i don't think "cannot create a small Javascript application" is a good title that helps any future readers.

Comment: @TilwinJoy - Can you, please, help me come up with a better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS file is being blocked by your browser's security settings as you are running on your local machine.

You either need to run the code under a web server or lower the security settings of the browser (not recommended). If you're running under windows, you can install IIS quite easily. Google for '[windows version] install IIS'.

Finally, never use W3Schools sites. They are full of incorrect information.

Comment: Inserting a _Mark of the Web_ into the document would solve the problem as well (if OP wants to do it without a web server).

Comment: @CBroe that's true, if he's happy to test in IE.

Comment: @brilliant you're trying to open a new window to it, so I guessed you were following one of their terrible tutorials ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - "you're trying to open a new window to it, so I guessed you were following one of their terrible tutorials ;)" - Yes, You are right. I couldn't even imagine that their tutorials could be wrong :(